# Why can variables with the same type and value print() differently?

Tags: r

Variables that appear to have the same type and value can produce different behavior when given as arguments to the `print()` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

a <- quantile(c(1), 1.0)
b <- c(1)

stopifnot(a == b)

print(class(a))
print(a)
print(class(b))
print(b)
```

The above will produce the following.

```
[1] "numeric"
100%
   1
[1] "numeric"
[1] 1
```

Somehow `print()` knows that `a` is a quantile and `b` is not even though this information is not available in their values or in the types reported by `class()`. What's going on?  Is there some sort of additional type information associated with `a` and `b`?

My understanding from the R documentation was that `a` and `b` are both of type `vector` with components of the `numerical` mode and that's all there is to know about their types.

Comment: Try `attributes(a)` and `names(a)`

Comment: Thanks. Now someone post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, try taking a look at:

```
names(a)
#[1] "100%"
```

and

```
attributes(a)
#$names
#[1] "100%"
```

This has nothing to do with the `class` or `mode` or `type` of object. `quantile()` has a `names=` argument that attaches to the output if set, which it is by default, as per `?quantile`

```
names: logical; if true, the result has a ‘names’ attribute.  Set to
       ‘FALSE’ for speedup with many ‘probs’.
```